# calling $item->getProduct() corrupts chosen custom options

Tags: php, magento

I've noticed an issue using item->getProduct() from within cart or checkout, for items that have custom options. In particular if you have a cart with two of the same product but different custom option selections.

For example: cart contains 2 x product A, one with custom option of size small (price +$0) and one with custom option of large (price +$5).

I observe the event 'catalog_product_get_final_price'

Here's my observer function:

```
public function onGetFinalPrice($observer)
{
    $items = $this->getCheckout()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $product = $item->getProduct();
    }

}
```

The price for both items in the cart will now be +$5. 
Here's the getProduct function from Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract:

```
 public function getProduct()
{
    $product = $this->_getData('product');
    if ($product === null && $this->getProductId()) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId())
            ->load($this->getProductId());
        $this->setProduct($product);
    }

    /**
     * Reset product final price because it related to custom options
     */
    $product->setFinalPrice(null);
    if (is_array($this->_optionsByCode)) {
        $product->setCustomOptions($this->_optionsByCode);
    }
    return $product;
}
```

It appears that the variable $_optionsByCode for the quote item is not retaining unique value. Calling getProduct() is resetting these values and therefore corrupting them. Any ideas for a fix here?

Comment: can you try `$item->getFinalPrice()` instead of `$item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()` ?

Comment: The call $item->getProduct() is required as within the observer I need to retrieve information from the product. My interest is why the custom options are reset when you perform this call.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of `catalog_product_get_final_price` use 
`checkout_cart_product_add_afte`r better process.because using `this event you set any price of product at cart.`

**configuration at  config.xml look :**

```
<events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <apply_custom_price>
                    <class>custompriceset/observer</class>
                    <method>applyCustomPrice</method>
                </apply_custom_price>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
```